# flutterのstreamBuilderとtab切り替えについて

Tags: flutter

Flutterでデータを取得するダミー部分を作成し
StreamBuilderを利用しGridviewに流し込む様に作って見ましたが、
tab切り替えを行うとstreamで流し込んだデータがなくなってしまいます。
StreamBuilderで設定した値は保持しておく様にしないといけないのでしょうか？

Bloc部分は下記の様に記載しました。

```
import 'dart:async';
class Bloc {

  final _dummy = StreamController<String>();

  Stream<List<String>> get dummy => _dummy.stream.transform(validateDummy).asBroadcastStream();

  final validateDummy = StreamTransformer<String, List<String>>.fromHandlers(handleData: (order, sink) {
      List<String> res = <String>[];
      res.add('data1');
      res.add('data2');
      res.add('data3');
      res.add('data4');
      res.add('data5');
      sink.add(res);
  });

  fetchRecommend(String name){
    _dummy.sink.add(name);
  }
  dispose() {
    _dummy.close();
  }
}
```